# Telerik ASP.NET ImageManager: Hide Elements

Tags: asp.net, telerik

After searching high and low for documentation and examples, I'm still stuck... so I'm hoping someone can help push me in the right direction.

I am using the "Image Manager" within the Telerik ASP.Net AJAX Editor.

I have everything working correctly, but there are 3 on-screen elements that appear in the image manager that I want to hide/remove.

1. New Folder Button
2. Current Path
3. Folder Tree

After much digging, I found a link under "Integration with SharePoint" that seems to show how to hide the "New Folder" icon: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/moss-modifying_the_editors_built_in_dialogs.html
[Of course, my issue has nothing to do with SharePoint, but this is the best I could find.]

If anyone has any insight on what properties to change, specifically for the path and folder tree, I would greatly appreciate it!

Many thanks in advance.

I'll keep plugging away and certainly if I figure it out, I'll post it here so others can benefit, since I'm sure I'm not the only one who would want to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the new folder button register the [external editor dialogs](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/externaldialogspath/defaultcs.aspx) (the EditorDialogs folder), open the FileBrowser.ascx file and set EnableCreateNewFolder="false" in the RadFileExplorer's declaration

```
<telerik:RadFileExplorer EnableCreateNewFolder="false" ... />
```

Via the VisibleControls property of the File Explorer, you can hide also the TreeView,Toolbar,Grid and the AddressBox, i.e. to hide the folder tree and address bar do not set their values:

```
<telerik:RadFileExplorer EnableCreateNewFolder="false" VisibleControls="Toolbar,Grid" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks Rumen! Much appreciated. I'll try this out and let you know. Cheers!